# Could not load type 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.BasicAuthCredential' from assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-sdk

I have an MVC app that pulls data from hosted TFS, and when I deploy it I get this error

```
Could not load type 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.BasicAuthCredential' from assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
```

However, I have Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client referenced in the project and the dll is on the server.

Why would it not be able to load Client.BasicAuthCredential from the dll and how would I go about fixing it?

Comment: Is VS Update 1 or greater installed on the server?

Comment: @ppejovic It is not. Is that the only way I could get it to work? VS appears to have to be installed on the C drive and there is not enough space on the C drive for it to be installed.

Comment: I believe the types you are using were introduced in update 1.

Answer (score 2):

We've had similar issues and after we installed TFS object model this issue was resolved. 
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a37e19fb-3052-4fc9-bef7-4a4682069a75

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.